# How to detect multiple classes in single ecg image using CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to AI/ML(also with python) I want to classification of ecg report based on the ecg Image
I have created a convolution neural network using keras with tensorflow. I have trained the model and the accuracy is more than 95%.
Below is the code snippet for the same.
I have ecg images kept in below folder type like class_names = ['F', 'M', 'N', 'Q', 'S', 'V']

```
model = Sequential([
  layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),

  
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),

  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),

  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),

  layers.Dropout(0.2),

  layers.Flatten(),

  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes, name="outputs")
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])


model.summary()

epochs=5
ecg_model = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)

model.save('ecg_model.h5')


ecg_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('ecg_model.h5')

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img("D:/Python/archive/ECG_Image_data/test/F/F1.png", target_size=(img_height, img_width))
image = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)

predictions = ecg_model.predict(image)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])


print(
    "This ECG image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
    .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
)
```

This is working fine by predicting only one class and its prediction score but one ecg image can have multiple class types present. How can I get multiple class names and prediction score accordingly ?  Also tried this questions answer and did not worked in my case. [How to detect multiple objects using my classification network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757359/how-to-detect-multiple-objects-using-my-classification-network)